# Is there a function that opens a file chooser minibuffer and returns an absolute file name?

Tags: completion

I want to write a function in my `init.el` file that basically opens a file-browser minibuffer for the user (the standard one or the one from helm) and returns an absolute file name to be used in another function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're describing `read-file-name` (which will use different UIs depending on the user's configuration and/or whether he triggered the current command with the mouse or with the keyboard).